# How to remove ARReferenceObject Anchor when the object is no longer in camera frame?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I am using `RealityKit` + `SwiftUI` + `ARSessionDelegate` to render 3D content on top of an `ARReferenceObject`. I want to remove the 3D content once the camera pans away from the object and it is no longer in the frame.

Currently I render the 3D content when the object is detected, which is what I want. But I have multiple identical objects that I want to identify separately using the same `ARReferenceObject`. So in order to do this I need to remove the original anchoring.

This is my wrapper for `SWiftUI`:

```
struct ARViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var arManager: ARManager
    // cretae alias for our wrapper
    typealias UIViewType = ARView
    
    // delegate for view representable
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(arManager: self.arManager)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        // create ARView
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero, cameraMode: .ar, automaticallyConfigureSession: true)
        // assign delegate
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        print("Updating View")
        // create anchor using an image and add it to the ARView
        let target = AnchorEntity(.object(group: "AR Resources", name: "bj"))
        target.name = "obj_anchor"
        // add anchor to AR world
        if(uiView.scene.anchors.count == 0){
           uiView.scene.anchors.append(target)
        }else{
           uiView.scene.anchors[0] = target
        }
        // add plane and title to anchor
        addARObjs(anchor: target, arObj: arManager.currARObj)
        return()
    }
}
```

This is my `Delegate`:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
    @ObservedObject var arManager: ARManager
    
    init(arManager: ARManager) {
        self.arManager = arManager
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        return
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]){
        return
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        return
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### SceneKit

You can do it in SceneKit. All you need is to use [isNode(_:insideFrustumOf:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522647-isnode?changes=latest_minor) instance method that returns a `Boolean value` indicating whether a node might be visible from a specified point of view or not. This method is also implemented in ARKit (as a part of SceneKit).

```
func isNode(_ node: SCNNode, insideFrustumOf pointOfView: SCNNode) -> Bool
```

Sample code:

```
var allYourNodes = [SCNNode]()
allYourNodes.append(node001)
allYourNodes.append(node002)

guard let pointOfView = arSCNView.pointOfView 
else { return }

for yourNode in allYourNodes {

    if !arView.isNode(yourNode, insideFrustumOf: pointOfView) {

        arSCNView.session.remove(anchor: yourARAnchor)
    }
}
```

However, I haven't found a similar method in RealityKit 2.0. Hope it'll be added by Cupertino engineers in the near future.

### RealityKit

Here's what we have in RealityKit 2.0 at the moment:

> **Apple's documentation says**: During an AR session, RealityKit automatically uses the device’s camera to define the perspective from which to render the scene. When rendering a scene outside of an AR session – with the view’s cameraMode property set to

```
ARView.CameraMode.nonAR
```

RealityKit uses a `PerspectiveCamera` instead. You can add a perspective camera anywhere in your scene to control the point of view. If you don't explicitly provide one, RealityKit creates a default camera for you.

So, the only available parameters of a `PerspectiveCameraComponent` at the moment are:

```
init(near: Float, far: Float, fieldOfViewInDegrees: Float)
```